# Jquery for loop generated bootstrap panel collapse not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I created multiple bootstrap panels using for loop with the help of Jquery.

The problem is that the tabpanel is not working, I am unable to expand nor collapse the panel body.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Shawn_fiddle/774tygny/)

```
<div class="container-fluid text-center" name="drawing">
  <h2><b> TTT </b></h2>
  <hr>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="container-fluid text-center col-sm-2" name="filters">
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid text-center col-sm-10" name="chart">
      <span id="chart1"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
var headingList = ["heading01", "heading02", "heading03", "heading04", "heading05", "heading06", "heading07", "heading08", "heading09", "heading10"];
var collapseList = ["collapse01", "collapse02", "collapse03", "collapse04", "collapse05", "collapse06", "collapse07", "collapse08", "collapse09", "collapse10"];
var labelList = ["v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5", "v6", "v7", "v8", "v9", "v10"];
var filterList = ["f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "f6", "f7", "f8", "f9", "f10"];

var i = 0,
  len = headingList.length;
for (i; i < len; i += 1) {
  console.log(headingList[i]);
  console.log(collapseList[i]);
  console.log(labelList[i]);
  console.log(filterList[i]);
  $("#accordion").append(
    '<div class="panel panel-default">' +
    '<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id=' + headingList[i] + '>' +
    '<h4 class="panel-title">' +
    '<a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href=' + collapseList[i] + ' aria-expanded="true" aria-controls=' + collapseList[i] + '>' +
    labelList[i] +
    '</a>' +
    '</h4>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div id=' + collapseList[i] + ' class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby=' + headingList[i] + '>' +
    '<div class="panel-body">' +
    '<select multiple id=' + filterList[i] + ' size="10"></select><br>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>'
  )
};
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just missed adding `#` to `<a>` tag `href` attribute

So replace

```
<a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href=' + collapseList[i] + ' aria-expanded="true" aria-controls=' + collapseList[i] + '>
```

with

```
<a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href=#' + collapseList[i] + ' aria-expanded="true" aria-controls=' + collapseList[i] + '>
```

in your js code

[Working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1vwf6t9n/)

Comment: Shame on me for missing that. Upvote and accept. Thanks.